# Defining Frequency Bands with Minim

Tags: java, fft, minim

I'm using a Minim BeatDetect object to analyze the incoming microphone signal. BeatDetect uses FFT.

In the BeatDetect class, there are four functions of interest: `isHat()`, `isKick()`, `isSnare()` and `isRange(int, int, int)`. The first three are customized versions of `isRange()`. What I'm trying to do is recognize more than just hat, kick and snare drums.

In order to do this, I need to understand the math in the methods `isHat()`, `isKick()` and `isSnare()`. I'm hoping someone here can help me. Here is the code for the 4 functions.

```
/**
 * In frequency energy mode this returns true if a beat corresponding to the
 * frequency range of a kick drum has been detected. This has been tuned to
 * work well with dance / techno music and may not perform well with other
 * styles of music. In sound energy mode this always returns false.
 * 
 * @return boolean: true if a kick drum beat has been detected
 * 
 * @example Analysis/FrequencyEnergyBeatDetection
 * 
 * @related BeatDetect
 */
public boolean isKick()
{
    if (algorithm == SOUND_ENERGY)
    {
        return false;
    }
    int upper = 6 >= spect.avgSize() ? spect.avgSize() : 6;
    return isRange(1, upper, 2);
}

/**
 * In frequency energy mode this returns true if a beat corresponding to the
 * frequency range of a snare drum has been detected. This has been tuned to
 * work well with dance / techno music and may not perform well with other
 * styles of music. In sound energy mode this always returns false.
 * 
 * @return boolean: true if a snare drum beat has been detected
 * 
 * @example Analysis/FrequencyEnergyBeatDetection
 * 
 * @related BeatDetect
 */
public boolean isSnare()
{
    if (algorithm == SOUND_ENERGY)
    {
        return false;
    }
    int lower = 8 >= spect.avgSize() ? spect.avgSize() : 8;
    int upper = spect.avgSize() - 1;
    int thresh = (upper - lower) / 3 + 1;
    return isRange(lower, upper, thresh);
}

/**
 * In frequency energy mode this returns true if a beat corresponding to the
 * frequency range of a hi hat has been detected. This has been tuned to work
 * well with dance / techno music and may not perform well with other styles
 * of music. In sound energy mode this always returns false.
 * 
 * @return boolean: true if a hi hat beat has been detected
 * 
 * @example Analysis/FrequencyEnergyBeatDetection
 * 
 * @related BeatDetect
 */
public boolean isHat()
{
    if (algorithm == SOUND_ENERGY)
    {
        return false;
    }
    int lower = spect.avgSize() - 7 < 0 ? 0 : spect.avgSize() - 7;
    int upper = spect.avgSize() - 1;
    return isRange(lower, upper, 1);
}

/**
 * In frequency energy mode this returns true if at least
 * <code>threshold</code> bands of the bands included in the range
 * <code>[low, high]</code> have registered a beat. In sound energy mode
 * this always returns false.
 * 
 * @param low
 *           int: the index of the lower band
 * @param high
 *           int: the index of the higher band
 * @param threshold
 *           int: the smallest number of bands in the range
 *           <code>[low, high]</code> that need to have registered a beat
 *           for this to return true
 * @return boolean: true if at least <code>threshold</code> bands of the bands
 *         included in the range <code>[low, high]</code> have registered a
 *         beat
 *         
 * @related BeatDetect
 */
public boolean isRange(int low, int high, int threshold)
{
    if (algorithm == SOUND_ENERGY)
    {
        return false;
    }
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = low; i < high + 1; i++)
    {
        if (isOnset(i))
        {
            num++;
        }
    }
    return num >= threshold;
}
```

I want to be able to recognize beats accurately across a range of instruments by manipulating the methods above. Can anybody help teach me what I need to recognize this?

Currently, I understand that the functions return `true` if a beat is detected within a specified range of frequency bands. What I don't understand is why the values for the parameters [low, high, threshold] in the functions correlate to specific instruments. Thanks for any input.